# Neo4j Cypher - How to query for multiple variables within a single traversal

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-traversal

I have a case of scenario that there are **TOURIST** who wants to travel and every country has **VISA** control and there is a path along countries so some of connections you are not allowed to visit that specific country. There are 3 types of **VISA (A,B,C)** and i want make a query that makes a single traversal and returns which tourists can go which countries with their VISA types. Each tourist can have variations of those 3 **VISA** types and it's mapped between edges of **COUNTRY** nodes as a property of a enum value like this :

**NOT_ALLOWED_TO_PASS**: 0
**VISA_A**: 1
**VISA_B**: 2
**VISA_C**: 4
**VISA_AB**: 3
**VISA_AC**: 5
**VISA_BC**: 6
**VISA_ABC**:7

I have 2 types of nodes and 2 types of relations;

node t > "**TOURIST**" which has t.name and id,

node c > "**COUNTRY**" which has c.name and id

relation r1 > "**CAN_START**" which has only id  *// tourist can start from it's linked nodes*

relation r2 > "**CAN_PASS**"  which has r.visa_type  *//enum that i explained above*

t - [r:can_start]-c

c- [r:can_pass]-c

I've achieved this with implementing this query below:

```
Match (t:Tourist)-[r1:CAN_START]-(c1:Country)
match path= (c1:Country) -[CAN_PASS*] -(c2:Country)
where all(r2 in relationships(path)where  r2.visa_type IN ["1","3","5","7"]) //this for visa_type A
return t.name as Tourist, c1.name+collect(c2.name) as CountryListWithTypeA
```

i can get my result with doing union etc but it traverses network 3 times.I want to get this 3 different results within a single traversal.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can OR the conditions like this:

```
Match (t:Tourist)-[r1:CAN_START]-(c1:Country)
match path=(c1:Country)-[CAN_PASS*]-(c2:Country)
where all(r2 in relationships(path) where r2.visa_type IN ["1","3","5","7"]) 
OR all(r2 in relationships(path) where r2.visa_type IN ["2","6"])
OR all(r2 in relationships(path) where r2.visa_type = "4")  
return t.name as Tourist, c1.name+collect(c2.name) as CountryListWithTypeA
```

Comment: that simply returns the first possible nodes for visa_A, i want to return 3 different columns which are : CountryListWithTypeA ,CountryListWithTypeB ,CountryListWithTypeC. And i want to do this within a  single traversal.